# Angular directive communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Recently I follow a free tutorial at https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-communication about directive communication along with it's example.

index.html

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <country>
        <state>
            <city></city>
        </state>
    </country>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('country', ['', function(){
    return {
        controller: function() {
            this.makeAnnouncement = function(message){
                console.log("Country says: " + message);
            };
        },
        restrict: 'E'
    };
}]);

app.directive('state', ['', function(){
    return {
        controller: function() {
            this.makeLaw = function(law){
                console.log("Law: " + law);
            };
        },
        restrict: 'E'
    };
}]);

app.directive('city', ['', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E', 
        require: ["^country","^state"],
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            controller[0].makeAnnouncement("from city");
            controller[1].makeLaw("Jump higher");
        }
    };
}]);
```

But it run into error, with error message `Unknown provider: Provider <-  <- cityDirective`. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
app.directive('country', ['', function(){
```

to this

```
app.directive('country', [function(){
```

Similar to state and city
And also, you have an extra } in state directive declaration

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/k2z5rjT0sva0y2QQnHHD?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works!! But why? Why `['', function(){` will not work? Isn't that the standard way to write in Angular especially if your script is going to be compressed?

Comment: yes, using array []  is the standard way when script is minified, but if you don't have any dependency, don't put anything in front of the function declaration in the array. If you put '', I guess it's considered as a dependency with a name is empty string, which is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It works if you remove all the explicit injections in your directives. Here's a working JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8ouskd3v/

I really like what egghead is doing but sometimes their code is not working properly when you just copy paste it.

---

You have an extra `}` in your `state` directive (after the `restrict: 'E'`). That's probably causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's just I accidentally put that in on the example here. In my code don't have that extra `}`.

Answer (score 0):

some resources you want to use in your directive like predefined services($http..etc),userdefined services....etc you may write syntax like this

app.directive('country', ['$http','myOwnService',
   function($http,myOwnService)

{

```
 //use service here.

}]);
```

If not used any inbuilt services or custom things inside directive,you may write directive syntax like this,this way your directive will load very fast.

app.directive('country',
   function()

{

```
 //write code here

});
```